# PyTelegramBotApi, как ответить на сообщение аудиозаписью?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Вот например как сделать так, что бы бот прислал мне что-то вроде этого:
[image: Вот например как сделать так, что бы бот прислал мне что-то вроде этого]

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def audiomessage(message):
    if message.text == 'Какое-то текстовое сообщение':
        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio=open('tests/test.mp3', 'rb'))
```

Больше примеров тут: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets